# Select everything between two characters without including them

Tags: php, regex

I've been trying to look around for how to select everything between two characters in a string.

Example string:

```
@ Some text here @
```

To select this I did:

```
/@(.*)@/
```

But it includes the `@` signs

I tried to use different methods I found online with no success.

Comment: What result are you trying to get?

Comment: Please supply some sample data and desired output, otherwise it's all guess work.

Comment: @Lix Yeah I used HTML tags which havent been visible, changed them to @ signs. I want to remove everything around the text that is between the @ signs

Comment: did you try this: `/@[\@]+@/`

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are unfamiliar with the concept of *capturing groups*. From "Some text here", you can extract "ex" in the middle of the word "text" using something like `/t(.+)t/`. While the entire match will be "text", group #1 will be just "ex".

You can use capturing groups in PHP by passing an empty variable/empty array as the third argument to [`preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

> If `$matches` is provided, then it is filled with the results of search.
>   `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern,
>   `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured
>   parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

What method are you working with? I'm gonna use `preg_match_all` to explain two possible regular expressions

```
$text = "hello @this is what i want@notthis!";

if (preg_match_all("/@([^@]*)@/", $text, $results))
    var_dump($results);
    // [0][0] "@this is what i want@"
    // [1][0] "this is what i want"

if (preg_match_all("/(?<=@)([^@]*)(?=@)/", $text, $results))
    var_dump($results);
    // [0][0] "this is what i want"
    // [1][0] "this is what i want"
```

If you have multiple occurences, you can loop through the first depth. So looping through `$results[1]` will always give you the correct string (since the brackets the string is in are the first in the searchable area).

As for the expressions:

1. The first one is the regular version. You look for a specified text (everything except *@*) inside specified characters. But since `preg_match_all` gives you the entire string it found plus the result, you get the @ as well.
2. The second expression uses so called lookaround. This means the characters insdie the first and last brackets are not part of the searched area but before/behind.